# ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

I am getting an error whenever I want to install Anaconda. I tried several version and the error keeps appearing.

```
Preparing transaction: ...working... done Executing transaction: ...working... WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(50): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing. environment location: D:\Programs\Anaconda3 registry file: C:\Users\livis.conda\environments.txt done ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'. Rolling back transaction: ...working... done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0 location of failed script: D:\Programs\Anaconda3\Scripts.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==

==> script output <== stdout: 1 file(s) copied.

stderr: The system cannot find the file specified. The system cannot find the file specified.

return code: 1
```

I tried uninstalling and then again installing, then restarting my PC several times.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So for those who are also having this issue. I completely uninstalled anaconda and didn't use it for a year. After many Windows updates, I have decided to reinstall anaconda just to check if it's still fricked up. And surprise surprise it was working again.